# phpMyAdmin lacking privileges

Tags: php, permissions, phpmyadmin, hosting

I have checked similar questions, but their solutions don't work for me. My website is hosted on Dreamhost. My phpMyAdmin looks very different to the phpMyAdmin shown in tuturials all over the internet. It says I have "no privileges" to create a database and there is no tab at the top of the phpMyAdmin page with the "privileges", "users", etc. tabs that are usually found there. The hosting was originally set up by my university. Is this an issue of permissions? Can it be solved or do I have to get a new host? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have at least one database already created by your provider? If the answer is yes, then they probably have a restriction, prohibiting you from adding new databases, and you must work with that one.

If you don't see any databases to work with, and you cannot create a new one, then you might be using a plan where no database access is included. The fact that you have access to phpMyAdmin seems to indicate that you do have DB access, and should be able to use at least one provided (pre-created), o create one yourself.

You should talk to Dreamhost to know what are you entitled to do with your account. They have plans with "unlimited" MySQL databases.